# static function pointer to external function

Tags: c++, function, pointers, static, external

is it possible to create a static function pointer to an external function?

I've tried several possible solutions, but non worked.

Here's the code:

```
template <class T>
    struct SIMD_type_traits {
    typedef T type;
};

template <>
struct SIMD_type_traits<int> {
    typedef __m128i type;
};

template <class T, class S = typename SIMD_type_traits<T>>
class SIMD_traits{
public:
    typedef T element_type;
    typedef typename S::type simd_type;
    typedef simd_type(*binaryFunction)(simd_type, simd_type);
    const static binaryFunction add;
};

static void noop(){
    throw std::string("no specialization for SIMD function");
}

template <class T, class S>
const typename SIMD_traits<T, S>::binaryFunction SIMD_traits<T, S>::add = ((SIMD_traits<T, S>::binaryFunction)noop);

template <>
const typename SIMD_traits<int>::binaryFunction SIMD_traits<int>::add = &_mm_add_epi32;
```

When compiling this code section I get this error:

```
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mm_add_epi32
1>....obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mm_add_epi32
1>c:\....exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

I'm aware, that the function `_mm_add_epi32` is external and that the function address will be resolved at link time, but is it possible to get this working?

Comment: What are the several possible solutions that you tried?

Comment: Those are not external functions, but ["intrinsics"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intrinsic_function) inlined by the compiler.

Comment: Are you trying to make a global static function pointer?  If these are both globals in separate compilation units, the linker is not going to resolve the order of instantiation.

Comment: @BoPersson, shouldn't MSVC refuse to compile the code instead of failing durink linking?

Comment: @Ignacio Bertacchini: I've tried schwarz counter and putting the initialization into the cpp file and others...

Comment: You have included  emmintrin.h, right? If you have check linker settings that you are not targeting titanium and remember /Oi switch to enable intrinsics

Comment: Refer: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/26td21ds(v=vs.100).aspx